# SSH: connection timed out

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, debian

I am trying to connect via SSH but I get `Connection timed out` and nothing I found on the internet on this topic yielded any results.

The Linux distro that I am trying to connect to is Debian:

The port SSH is listening to is the default one: `22`
[image: The port SSH is listening to is the default one: 22]

As far as I can tell there is no firewall:
[image: As far as I can tell there is no firewall]

`ip addr` output:
[image: ip addr output]

`nmap 10.0.2.15 -Pn` output:
[image: nmap output]

`ssh root@10.0.2.15` output:
[image: ssh output]

Comment: you showed just the configuration, but did not provide information if the ssh is running on the server you want to connect. can you provide the output of `netstat -anutp | grep :22`

Comment: Can you ping 10.0.2.15? Does nectat to that IP on port 22 succeed? Do you see ssh running in ps output on that machine? Do you see a listening entry for port 22/ssh in sockstat or netstat on that machine? Basically do a step by step - make sure connectivity is there, process is up, listening socket is present and socket accepts connections.

Comment: On the machine, I am trying to connect to everything seems to be fine. But I cannot ping it, I cannot connect using netcat. [ssh service](https://ibb.co/kKtSLKC). As in my question, I checked to see if the firewall is blocking connections, but it allows all connections. Could there be something else that is blocking the connection?

Comment: It definitely seems that way. What is in between the two devices?

Comment: is this a VirtualBox VM running on your computer? And you have only a NATted adapter? I always add to VB VMs two network adapters. One NATted for Internet access and the second a Host-Only adapter through which I connect to the VM from my laptop.

Comment: It is a VirtualBox VM running on my computer, but I have to admit that you lost me with the other stuff.

Comment: The VBox NATted network is not exposed to your host. You can check that with ipconfig - there will be no 10.0.2.x IP. So you create a HostOnly network in VBox Host Network Manager  which will create a network adapter on your host through which you will be able to reach the host. Another option would be to [port forward the traffic from your host to the VM's IP](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#natforward) - the first option is the easier one as you will be able to use default ports. - see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The VBox NATted network is not exposed to your host.**

You can check that with ipconfig and route - there will be no 10.0.2.x IP/route - so the traffic from you host will be going to the default gateway and get lost using the default route (most probably to your router and then to the Internet)

Screenshots from my Mac OS VirtualBox.

**Resolution** - You have two options:

1. Create HostOnly Network for access:

[image: File->Host Network Manager]

So you create a HostOnly network in VBox Host Network Manager which will create a network adapter on your host through which you will be able to reach the host. 
In my example I used the 192.168.56.x/24 with DHCP enabled.

The first NATted adapter (which you have on your VM):

[image: First adapter]

Then add a second adapter to the VM using the created network and select HostOnly and the network you created:

[image: Second adapter connected to the created network]

After you have added the vmnic - you might need to configure it.
See my ifconfig:

[image: ifconfig output]

first adapter - 10.0.2.4

second adapter - 192.168.56.104 - on top of screenshot you can see that I used this IP to connect with ssh.

2. Port forward from your host to the VM

Another option would be to [port forward the traffic from your host to the VM's IP](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#natforward)

**IMHO:**
The first option is the easier one as you will be able to use default ports, while the second will mean one non-default free port on your host to the port 22 for each VM.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will leave here a [link](https://www.tecmint.com/network-between-guest-vm-and-host-virtualbox/) that goes into more detail about configuring the network between host and VM, if anyone in the future stumbles into the same problem.

Comment: looks nice! will for sure help a lot of people.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Port Forwarding, you need to connect to localhost. Its kind of obvious, but i needed some time to figure that out ;)

```
ssh user@127.0.0.1 -p 10001 <-- The Host-Port you configured
```